# regular expression to detect integers followed by some string format

Tags: php, regex

I have the following check currently to match if a string is a not a number

```
if (!ctype_digit($matching)) {

}
```

however now I wanted to change this such that I wanted to detect the following format:

```
xxxk
xxxrb
xxx.xxxx
```

or any numbers

What is the best regular expression to detect this? X here is an integer/digits between 0-9 and it can be any length. So for example, here's a valid match:

```
8k
72k
123k
899rb
20rb
5rb
160.000
1.600.218
```

Comment: x being any character or just x?

Comment: did you want to match also the integers ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but it may be a good idea to include more examples of what you want to match. (e.g. if you wanted to allow integers and a few special characters an example may look like `xxx-12_4$aq`)

Comment: also, can I ask if it every string starts with "xxx" or are those just place holders? Does this also mean that each string is at least 3 characters long?

Comment: @Dalorzo x here is a digit between 0-9

Comment: ok I updated my answer to accommodate for this

Comment: I have added more examples to clarify

Comment: ok that's good what's the minimum number of characters? None of your examples go below 2, is that accurate?

Comment: It looks like your question changed quite a bit since you first asked. Do you want to match those numbers, or not match them? Because you show in your code example `(!ctype)`, which is not match.

Comment: I want to check if they don't match those formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:k|rb|(?:\.\d{3})+|\d+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/bL8nO3/3)**

[image]

The php code is:

```
$re = "/^\\d{1,3}(?:k|rb|(?:\\.\\d{3})+|\\d+)$/m"; 
$str = "8k\n72k\n123k\n899rb\n20rb\n5rb\n160.000\n1.600.218"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Can you try to put this into preg_match_all, I tried the following and it didn't work preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}(?:k|rb|(?:/\.\d{3})+|\d+)', 'Anak anak kampung 120k', $matchess);

Comment: @adit, This matches `ctype_digit`; I was under the impression you didn't want to match digits? i.e. `1234`, `999999`, etc.

Comment: @adit if you go to the link I put on my answer and then go to Code Generation section you can obtain the code for your needs. I'll update my answer with the php code

Comment: @l'L'l as OP put in the question it should match the patterns and `or any numbers`. In case that doesn't mean any number it can be easily fixed by removing the last `|\d+` from the regex

Comment: @Fede, yes that makes sense. I read it originally as 'if not a numeric char (xor) this pattern then match`.

Comment: @Fede what if I want to change it such that it says doesn't match any of those

Comment: @adit if you don't want to match numbers like 1234 you have to remove `|\\d+` from the regex

Answer (score 0):

Based on the strings you would like to match, here is the regex:

```
/^\d[0-9a-z\.]+$/i
```

[Working example](http://regex101.com/r/gT7yT2/1) (please keep in mind that I added the `g` and `m` parameters so it would match each example)

If you need to make sure that all decimal points have 3 digits after them then it gets a little more complex:

```
/^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}?)*(?:[a-z]+)?$/i
```

[More complex example](http://regex101.com/r/fH6aO3/1)

**Update:**

Now works according to all new examples.

Comment: I added some examples above

Comment: @adit ok, I updated my answer to allow for the new examples. The first expression will search very generally and will typically be accurate; the second expression is more strict because it will only allow decimal points if there are 3 digits after them. But both work as expected on your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me offer a generic solution based on what I understood about your format.

In Regular Expression you can use `|` meaning or so based on your multiple format those can be expressed with or's like this:

```
x{3}k|x{3}rb|x{3}\.x{4}|\d+
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bG8vO2/1)

Each `|`(or) represents one of the formats(expression) you may be allowing/evaluating.

Since `x` is not specify in your post please note `x` can be easily replaced by letters with `[a-zA-Z]` expression or by numbers with `[0-9]` expression or a combination of both like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
\A\d+(?:(?:\.\d{3})*|k|rb)\z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$matching = "120.000";
$re = "/^(\b\d{1,3}|k|rb|\.\d{3}\b)*$/";

if (!ctype_digit($matching)) {
    if (!preg_match($re, $matching, $matches)) {
        echo "ctype_digit/regex not matched";
    } else {
        echo "regex pattern matched";
    }
} else {
    echo "ctype_digit matched";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
\d[.\d]*(?:rb|k)?
```